# How to extract data from stdclass object using php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a stdclass objects and I want to extract img data from that objects but I have done like below but it is not working.

Below is my code,

```
foreach ($values->design->front as $front => $frontdata){
          $front_data = str_replace("'", '"',$frontdata);
          $front_values = json_decode($front_data);
          // //echo $front_values[1]['id'];
          // echo "<pre>";print_r($front_values);
          // //echo $front_data[1]['img'];
          foreach($front_values as $val){
            //echo "<pre>";print_r($val);
           echo $val->img;
          }
        }
```

My resultant Array,

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => area-design
)
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => images-1
    [width] => 500px
    [height] => 500px
    [top] => 0px
    [left] => 0px
    [zIndex] => auto
    [img] => http://192.168.1.156/dutees/tshirtecommerce//uploaded/products/dg-designer-f127a3f7144332566936559141210548143.png
)
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => area-design
)
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => images-1
    [width] => 500px
    [height] => 500px
    [top] => 0px
    [left] => 0px
    [zIndex] => auto
    [img] => http://192.168.1.156/dutees/tshirtecommerce//uploaded/products/dg-designer-f127a3f7144332566936559141210548143.png
)
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => area-design
)
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => images-1
    [width] => 500px
    [height] => 500px
    [top] => 0px
    [left] => 0px
    [zIndex] => auto
    [img] => http://192.168.1.156/dutees/tshirtecommerce//uploaded/products/dg-designer-464d828b14433256696212312871108713.png
)
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => area-design
)
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => images-1
    [width] => 500px
    [height] => 500px
    [top] => 0px
    [left] => 0px
    [zIndex] => auto
    [img] => http://192.168.1.156/dutees/tshirtecommerce//uploaded/products/dg-designer-ee23e7ad144332566992049430410306091.png
)
```

From above array I want to extract only img data i.e, images How I can resolve this please help me someone.

$values->design->front contains below array,

```
Array
(
    [0] => {'0':{'id':'area-design'},'1':{'id':'images-1','width':'500px','height':'500px','top':'0px','left':'0px','zIndex':'auto','img':'http://192.168.1.156/dutees/tshirtecommerce//uploaded/products/dg-designer-f127a3f7144332566936559141210548143.png'}}
)
Array
(
    [0] => {'0':{'id':'area-design'},'1':{'id':'images-1','width':'500px','height':'500px','top':'0px','left':'0px','zIndex':'auto','img':'http://192.168.1.156/dutees/tshirtecommerce//uploaded/products/dg-designer-f127a3f7144332566936559141210548143.png'}}
    [1] => {'0':{'id':'area-design'},'1':{'id':'images-1','width':'500px','height':'500px','top':'0px','left':'0px','zIndex':'auto','img':'http://192.168.1.156/dutees/tshirtecommerce//uploaded/products/dg-designer-464d828b14433256696212312871108713.png'}}
    [2] => {'0':{'id':'area-design'},'1':{'id':'images-1','width':'500px','height':'500px','top':'0px','left':'0px','zIndex':'auto','img':'http://192.168.1.156/dutees/tshirtecommerce//uploaded/products/dg-designer-ee23e7ad144332566992049430410306091.png'}}
)
```

Comment: Could you provide what contains in `$front_data`?

Comment: How you are getting this array? before you start looping, use the `json_decode` and show the results

Comment: can you show us the exact output of `echo "<pre/>";print_r($values->design->front);`? add it before first `foreach()` and paste the output in your question

Comment: @Timur $front_data contains =>" {"0":{"id":"area-design"},"1":{"id":"images-1","width":"500px","height":"500px","top":"0px","left":"0px","zIndex":"auto","img":"http://192.168.1.156/dutees/tshirtecommerce//uploaded/products/dg-designer-f127a3f7144332566936559141210548143.png"}} "

Comment: @alive to die  below is output, Array
(
    [0] => {'0':{'id':'area-design'},'1':{'id':'images-1','width':'500px','height':'500px','top':'0px','left':'0px','zIndex':'auto','img':'http://192.168.1.156/dutees/tshirtecommerce//uploaded/products/dg-designer-f127a3f7144332566936559141210548143.png'}}
)

Comment: @Mohakumar  add it into your question please. really hard to read

Answer (score 0):

If your $frontdata array is

```
Array ( [0] => {'0':{'id':'area-design'},'1':{'id':'images-1','width':'500p‌​x','height':'500px',‌​'top':'0px','left':'‌​0px','zIndex':'auto'‌​,'img':'192.168.1.15‌​6/dutees/tshirtecomm‌​erce//uploaded/produ‌​cts/…;}} )
```

Try this,

```
foreach ($values->design->front as $front => $frontdata){
    foreach($front_data as $val){


               echo $val[1]['img'];

    }
}
```

Comment: It showing Invalid arguements supplied for foreach.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer working with JSON after `json_decode` like with array. For it add second argument `true` i.e. `json_decode($front_data, true)`
Try this:

```
foreach ($values->design->front as $front => $frontdata){
    $front_data = str_replace("'", '"',$frontdata);
    $front_values = json_decode($front_data, true);
    // //echo $front_values[1]['id'];
    // echo "<pre>";print_r($front_values);
    // //echo $front_data[1]['img'];
   foreach($front_values as $val){
      //echo "<pre>";print_r($val);
      if(isset($val['img'])) {
          echo $val['img'];
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It showing cannot convert object of stdclass to array

Comment: Did you add `true` to `json_decode($front_data, true)`?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use `json_decode` and `json_encode` on the object like in this example: https://eval.in/803391

```
$result =[];
//first encode and then decode, to not get any errors 
$array = json_decode(json_encode($frontdata), true);
var_dump( $array );
foreach($array as $val){
  if(isset($val['img'])){
      //save into a result array
      $result[]=$val['img'];
  }
}
var_dump($result);
```